# lucee error says Entity does not exist, even if the component exists

Tags: coldfusion, lucee, coldbox

I am newbie in Lucee administration, I am trying to set up coldbox application but every time I am getting this error:

```
entity [ABC] with cfc name [model.abc.ABC] does not exist, existing entities are [def,qwe,xyz,dws,dgd]
```

I could not found anything in web, Can any body help me out in this ?

Thanks
Ritu

Comment: Wonder if it has something to do with your directory structure

Comment: Best place to get help on something like this would be the CFML/Box slack channel.

Comment: Can you share the HQL that is throwing the error as well as the component definition? Also make sure you have any mappings you need set up in Lucee.

Comment: Does your ORM log mention anything about this? If you have   `skipCFCWithError = true` set, you wont know why it wasn't skipped unless you look in the ORM logs.

Also, ColdBox by default looks in the MODELS folder now, not Model... is your ORM cfclocations setup for the MODEL folder or maybe just the newer MODELS folder?